# Print syntax highlighted error description

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Following is a screenshot of Vim highlighting the closing bracket (`)`) red,

[image]

How can I know why vim thinks it's an error (or whatever it is)? How can I print the description of the reason for highlighting in red?

Comment: If it's not from LSP, you likely won't get a _description_ of the error. You can find the exact error vim is highlighting, though, with `command! SynName  echo synIDattr(synID(line("."), col("."), 1), "name")`. Run this command when cursor is on the error and it should print what the error is.

Comment: @kadekai to be more precise: the command you show defines a command `SynName` which will show the syntax group under the cursor. (There are better variations because there can be more than one such group.) The syntax group is likely to be what triggered the highlighting, though, which you can confirm with a mix of `:highlight` and `:syntax` commands.